# How can I see a logfile in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, kibana, fluentd

I am new to EFK and to Kibana. I have set up Fluentd (Daemonset), Elasticsearch and Kibana in our project.
For Fluentd I have used the available installation option from Rancher (Tools>Logging).

I have a microservice which is writing a logfile to /var/log/containers/claim/trace.log

Fluentd must ship all files located in /var/log/containers to Elasticsearch.

I am trying to find trace.log in Kibana unfortunatelly to no avail.
Where or how can I see my trace.log file in Kibana?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Mouna,
  Welcome to stack overflow. Why don't you use file beats to transfer the logs to elastic search and view it via Kibana?

Comment: Please show your fluentd's configuration.